# How do I insert line breaks in an HtmlDocument?

Tags: asp.net, html, web

I'm using the [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) to copy html content from several files that only contain `body` elements and their inner HTML, into a single, new html file. The essential code that does this is as follows. The `_pageDoc` is the `HtmlDocument` for the new file, and `contentNode` is a child of that doc, while for each file I build a `div` and append it to `contentNode`.

```
var contents = GetContentDescs(courseId);
foreach (var content in contents)
{
    var html = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(HtmlDir, content.ContentId + ".html"));
    var contentDoc = new HtmlDocument();
    contentDoc.LoadHtml(html);

    var bodyNode = contentDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("body").Single();
    var contentDiv = _pageDoc.CreateElement("div");
    contentDiv.InnerHtml = bodyNode.InnerHtml;
    contentNode.AppendChild(contentDiv);
}
```

This works as expected and the rendered html is perfect, but every `contentDiv` is on one line, and not very readable. How can I insert a line break in the html file (**vs in the rendered html**) between each `contentDiv`?

Answer (score -1):

Something like

```
HtmlNode linebreak = doc.CreateElement("br");    
var contentDivs= doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("contentDiv");
    for (int i = 0; i < contentDivs.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0)
        {
            doc.DocumentNode.InsertBefore(linebreak1, contentDivs[i]);
        }
    }
```

I've put up some dirty code by reading documentation but I've never used Agility pack

Comment: I said specifically I don't want line breaks that render, i.e. `br`, in the doc the user sees. I want line breaks in the actual HTML document's text. Not the text the user sees, the text I see in my HTML editor. This can't be done by inserting an element - it needs something like an `Environment.Newline` in the HTML code.

Comment: I even said, "the rendered html is perfect".

Comment: @ProfK Have fun solving your problem :)

Comment: Thanks - I'm sure it's going to quite a quest. Luckily my the VS Code editor formats code nicely for when I'm working with it, but I'm generating it, so I lose formatting every time a regenerate the code.